# Where in PhpStorm 2020.3.1 import IDE settings?

Tags: phpstorm

Where in PhpStorm 2020.3.1 I can import IDE settings
from priorly saved settings.jar file ?

Thanks!

Comment: In the `File` menu as usual. `File | Manage IDE Settings`. **NOTE:** This option is unavailable if you are syncing your settings with JetBrains Account OR some GitHub repo (there are 2 bundled plugins for that) -- see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings

Comment: @LazyOne it's available since 2020.3 where the https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-202548 is fixed; so the actions are there even if settings sync is enabled

Comment: @lena I remember that ticket. But PhpStorm's 2020.3 / IDEA's 2020.3 help page tells otherwise: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings / https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings

Comment: it's a bug in Help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **File | Manage IDE Settings | Import Settings**; see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.3/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#import-export-settings.

Despite the warning in Help, the actions are available even if settings synchronization through a [settings repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.3/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository) or [Settings Sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.3/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#IDE_settings_sync) is enabled.